# Should I put a space between a number and its unit?

Tags: spacing, siunitx, units

No too much more to say.

`\( 2.63\si\ohm \)` looks odd. But it might be the correct way.

`\( 2.64\,\si\ohm \)` looks much better IMO. What about the `\,`? Sould it be bigger, smaller or there is no really a convention for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As the [NIST Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf) states

> **7.2 Space between numerical value and unit symbol**
>
> In the expression for the
> value of a quantity, the unit symbol
> is placed after the numerical value
> and a space is left between the
> numerical value and the unit symbol.
> The only exceptions to this rule are
> for the unit symbols for degree,
> minute, and second for plane angle
> (...) in which case no space is left
> between the numerical value and the
> unit symbol.

Note that this is what happens if you use the `siunitx` as intended, namely by using `\SI{<value>}{<unit>}` (*see update note below*) to print a quantity:

```
\SI{2.63}{\ohm}
```

yields

[image]

#### Update note

Since version v3 of `siunitx`, `\SI` was changed to `\qty` (along with a bunch of other commands that you can [learn about in the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf#page=54)). Therefore, `\qty{2.63}{\ohm}` is preferred.

Comment: Note that the quantity is formally a product of the number and the unit, so the space here is showing multiplication.

Comment: @Joseph: Thinking of the quantity as a product of number and unit can be quite useful (e.g. it explains why in tables and graphs, the unit should be separated from the dimension by a forward slash indicating division), but one has to be a bit careful: While different units may be separated by a raised dot to indicate the multiplicative nature, this is not permitted between the number and the units.

Comment: That's a typographic convention: in terms of unit analysis these are all products.

Comment: @JosephWright I disagree. It's simply a notational convention. Jake is right. The same way the "dx" in an integral is in ordinary analysis not multiplied with the function term (unless you reinterpret it as a differential to justify the notational abuse in retrospect), the correct way to think of a number-unit cluster is as a pair <number,dimension>. To convince you of this: no number can ever modify a dimension and no dimension can ever modify a number. When you think of "2m" denoting "two meters", this really means "2m = 2 * 1m" (= 2 * <1,m>), *not* "2 * m".

Comment: @Jake [still addressing Joseph, but I'd like Jake to see this:] There are other constraints: not only does one never write "34·m" (like Jake has pointed out), one also never writes things like "m·1kg"; it must be "1 kg m" or "1 kg·m", and the reason is that there is an underlying constraint (normally obeyed, though I'm sure there are exceptions) that no unit cluster is preceded by nothing. Technically speaking, "(3m²)/(m)" (displayed as an ordinary fraction) is notational abuse as well, because it should parse as "3 (m²)/(m)", but admittedly that is tolerated.

Comment: @JosephWright One can also think of this as follows: the numbers occupy the field ℝ and the units occupy the space of a "[free commutative group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) generated/spanned by the 7 SI base units". A product <n1,u1>*<n2,u2> is defined as <n1*n2,u1*u2>, with the two sides of the pair never interacting in any way. Your view combines the field ℝ and the free commutative group into a single multiplicative algebraic structure, which you can in theory do (and you *do* (*almost*; see above) do it notationally) but there is no theoretical insight from doing so.

Comment: @JosephWright Okay, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Mathematical_properties) says essentially the same thing; the phrasing above with free commutative groups I just made up myself. Saying that "34·m" is really "multiplication" works because, *because* the numbers and units never interact, it's possible to keep them in the same formula without ever having confusion. While the Wiki article's "vector space" view is consistent with a "multiplication" view, the point really is that the two *real* multiplications are the number-number and unit-unit ones.

Comment: @JosephWright In any vector space, the "multiplication" between an element of the field and a vector (here: unit cluster) is also a form of multiplication but it's an uninteresting one and it's conceptually different from that between coefficients/reals/numbers and that between vectors (in the Wiki article's vector space model, what I call multiplication between vectors is really addition; I hope this doesn't cause confusion with what I wrote).

Comment: @JosephWright Though *admittedly*, the whole unit prefix business violates what I just wrote. They are notationally an extension of the unit space but algebraically just a bunch of real numbers. Thinking about it, it's an interesting observation that they can only attach immediately before a unit. I think the reason is that conceptually people want more units for practical reasons (which is why those prefixes attach to individual units), but that doesn't change their simple real-number semantics.

Comment: May I follow up asking: should I put a space between number (or number with unit) and math_operator? for example: 1 m x 2 m, or 1 mx2 m?

Comment: what about %? 5% or 5 %?

Comment: @wordsforthewise: See section 7.10.2 of the document I linked to: "a space is left between the symbol % and the number by which it is multiplied"

Comment: And what about currency like UK pence `10p`

Comment: Is this doable in a `references.bib` file? An article title includes, for example, "1 km". How is this situation to be dealt with?

Answer (score 37):

This is more of an answer to an answer (too long for a comment; no picture), but hopefully it'll serve as an illustration to the question as well:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\hilit{\hskip-.1pt\smash{% negative skip for the vrule width
  \special{color push rgb 1 0 0}\vrule width.1pt height4.5ex depth6ex\special{color pop}}}
\begin{document}
  \SI{2.63}{\ohm}               \par
  $2.63\hilit\,\hilit\Omega$    \par % which is the same thing as...
  $2.63\mskip\thinmuskip\Omega$ \par % which is the same thing as...
  $2.63\mskip3mu\Omega$         \par % 1em == 18mu; mu == "math unit"
  $dx\,dy$                      \par
  %
  $2.63\hphantom{\cdot}\Omega$  \par % we're talking about a product
  % product = "a quantity obtained by multiplying quantities together, or from
  % an analogous algebraic operation." --New Oxford American Dictionary
  $2.63\hilit~\hilit\Omega$     \par % ~ == "non-breakable space" or "tie-in"
\end{document}
```

[image: unitspace]

Comment: Great comparison. I'll stick with the `siunitx` way for now.

Comment: Please add a few words about your example. As it is, this answer doesn't even explain what it is showing or in reply to which comment.

Comment: @lblb did you notice the comments inside the code block?

Comment: @morbusg: Yes, but I still find your answer a bit lacking when a reader has to look through the code to find out what it is supposed to show. And as you didn't intend to answer the question, it is misplaced as it is.

Comment: @lblb fair enough. Feel free to downvote as I’m a little hesitant to delete the answer seeing it has been helpful to others.

Answer (score 5):

My preference would be `\;\si\ohm` rather than `\,\si\ohm` or `\si\ohm`. As Jake mentions, there is a convention, though it strikes me as ill-defined. "A space" is either literal or typographically ambiguous. Definitely some kind of space is preferable to none, but the exact size is likely up to personal taste outside of technical papers (where the behavior is defined, one hopes) or when not using the facilities provided by `siunitx`.

Comment: @Jake Well, that's me sorted. :D

Comment: you could delete the answer, then

Comment: @Simon Edited instead to still be correct and useful, but not to steal Jake's thunder, so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

Some arguments none of the existing anwers provide:

- A number with unit is a multiplication, which in mathematics is shown with a space between the factors. That's why math fonts are supposed to have wider sidebarings in their characters: make them look like multiplied individual objects instead of one word.
- It makes sense from a language consistency standpoint: a unit symbol can be thought of as an abbreviation for a longer word. You wouldn't suddenly remove the space before a word just because it is abbreviated. (A stands for Apple. I give you 8A vs. I give you 8 Apples)
- I have the suspicion that people want the number and unit to stay on the same line in their text application but are ignorant of or unable to use a nonbreaking space.
- Many practical uses of number-unit combinations don't want to waste the space needed for a number-unit separation. Think of a tiny electronic component that needs a value printed on it. If there's even a unit included, it always is slapped right after the number for space saving and therefore tradition. Because if not, the font size would need to decrease so less people will be able to read the printing correctly. Things like this teach people unconsciously about not using a space, even if one would be correct to use.